# How do I detect the users touch on an element in react native?

Tags: react-native, touch

I understand in react native we have:
 - OnPress (detects a press and release)
 - OnPressIn (detects the user going from not touching, to touching the button)
 -OnPressOut (detects the user releasing the button, or moving their finger elsewhere)

But I want to detect when the user is already touching the screen elsewhere, and then drags their finger over the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `PanResponder` API to have fine-grained control over touches and gestures. Create `PanHandlers` and attach them to the `View`you want to detect touches on.

For your use case of detecting drag, you can use the `onPanResponderMove`

```
onPanResponderMove: (evt, gestureState) => {
    // The most recent move distance is gestureState.move{X,Y}
    // The accumulated gesture distance since becoming responder is
    // gestureState.d{x,y}
  }
```

Use `dx` and `dy` to get the distance dragged on X and Y axes.

Here's the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/panresponder.html) on `PanResponder`

Comment: This seems to be on the right track, but how can I determine what element the user's finger is on? I can get the node ID from the event, but how do I know which element that relates to?

Comment: Actually, it looks like using node ID will not work, as it seems to always relate to the node on which the touch started, so I guess I will need to use the screen coordinates to calculate if the touch is above.